# issue on web scraping with python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I want to scrape this website :https://annumed.sante-dz.com/annuaire . The code I've written is working, but it's giving me an empty database with just the columns and no rows. I'm not sure what the issue is.

```
 import os
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import pandas as pd

 URL = 'https://annumed.sante-dz.com/annuaire'
 
 response = requests.get(URL)
 
 if response.status_code == 200:
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
 
 #Trouver tous les éléments "div" avec la classe "element"
 elements = soup.find_all('div', class_='element')
 
 professionnels = []
 specialites = []
 categories = []
 adresses = []
 
 Parcourir les éléments et extraire les informations
 for element in elements:
 professionnel = element.find('h3').text.strip()
 specialite = element.find('span', class_='tag speciliate').text.strip()
 categorie = element.find('a', href_='/filter/type/me').text.strip()
 adress = element.find('div', itemprop_='addressLocality').text.strip()
 
 professionnels.append(professionnel)
 specialites.append(specialite)
 categories.append(categorie)
 adresses.append(adress)
 
 Créer un DataFrame pandas à partir des informations
 data = {
         'Professionnel': professionnels,
         'Spécialité': specialites,
         'Catégorie': categories,
         'adress': adresses
     }
 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 Chemin où vous souhaitez enregistrer le fichier Excel
 save_path = r'C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\scraping_sante'
 os.makedirs(save_path, exist_ok=True)  # Crée le dossier s'il n'existe pas
 Enregistrer le DataFrame au format Excel
 excel_filename = os.path.join(save_path, 'professionnels_sante.xlsx')
 df.to_excel(excel_filename, index=False)

 print(f"Données extraites et enregistrées dans {excel_filename}")
 else:
 print(f"La requête a échoué avec le code d'état : {response.status_code}")
```

This website contains healthcare professionals in Algeria, and I want to extract a database that includes all professionals along with their categories, specialties, and addresses.But the result is always an empty database without any rows.

Comment: Please repost your code readably. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: The site may use JavaScript to retrieve and show the information. If so, you need something like Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data from the page you can use next example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = []
for page in range(1, 3):   # <-- increase number of pages here
    print("Page", page)
    url = f"https://annumed.sante-dz.com/annuaire?page={page}"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    for i in soup.select(".info:has(header)"):
        name = i.h3.text
        spec = i.select_one("header p").text
        cats = [s.text for s in i.select(".speciliate")]
        addr = i.select_one(".address__wrapper").get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
        data.append((name, spec, ",".join(cats), addr))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Spec", "Categories", "Address"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                              Name                   Spec                                                                  Categories                    Address
0                                          Mahalli                Médecin                                                           Médecine Générale          Mohamadia , Alger
1                              DR BENHAMIDA ADNANE                Médecin  Médecine Générale,Esthetique,Sexologue,Nutrition,Andrologue,Mésothérapeute       Dar El Beïda , Alger
2       Cabinet d'ophtalmologie dr boudoucha amine                Médecin                                                               Ophtalmologue       El Harrouch , Skikda
3  CGSA Clinique Gestion du Stress et de l'Anxiété               Clinique                                                                                          Hydra , Alger
4                              Dr BENDADA MOHAMMED                Médecin                                                                 Psychiatrie           Birtouta , Alger
5                                   Bouzid Arbaoui                Médecin                                                          Gastro-Entérologue          Tlemcen , Tlemcen
6                                 medecin de garde               Clinique                                                                                        Béjaïa , Béjaïa
7                                   Wahida CHOUITI                Médecin                                                                 Cardiologue    Ain Tadles , Mostaganem
8                          Maimour .A ep Bouyoucef                Médecin                                         Médecine Interne,Médecin vasculaire  Constantine , Constantine
9       Laboratoire d'Analyses Médicales El Hanaa   Laboratoire d'Analyse                                                                                         Draria , Alger
```

Comment: And how can I proceed to access all 4308 pages to extract all the professionals?